# How to parse Oracle DB to SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I am looking to purchase data from our local County Gov office who supplies the data as a flat file where we parse it based on character position into our current SQL Server database.

But I would rather take the data directly from some sort of Export from Oracle ( The counties Database is Oracle) then using Microsofts Data Import bring this directly into my SQL Server 2008 database.

Is there such a possibility or what is the best method/practice to achieve this goal? Are the tools present in the Export from Oracle and Import to SQL Server? OR do I need consider purchasing conversion software or programing the solution?

The reason not to use the flat file is that we only target some of the values not the whole database which I would like to import for added resources in our project.

Sorry for not being more clear in my description/question

Comment: This question doesn't make sense.  How did Oracle get involved here?  As far as I can tell you are talking about plain text files and SQL Server.

Comment: Why does the fixed length flat file not meet your requirements?  You should be able to run through the Import Data Wizard and use SSIS to import the flat file with about 5 minutes of effort.

Comment: Updated the question with reference to Oracle and why we are looking to import the whole DB over the few values we currently import from flat files.

Comment: Micheal Fredrickson, SSIS may be the solution to this problem. I will have to research this. Thanks

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We import and export daily to Oracle databases that our customers have. Typically, they provide us with a flat file containing the information we need (we tell them but if you are purchasing, you may be stuck with whatever they are selling) and then we import it using SSIS. Ther eason that we do this is that most companies (and government agencies for that matter) are unwilling to actually provde the whloe data and its schema to someone else as that information is proprietary. Plus the whole database may be rather large and contain many things we don't need.

If the Oracle database is your own and on your servers, you can set up a linked server and directly query it.

Comment: I own MS SQL but not Oracle. SSIS seems to be the solution.